# Getting Features from Clusters in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have an array with lots of different locations, with names and pictures and of course longitude and latitude. If I put these onto the map directly, it gets cluttered. So I try to use the [Clusters](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster).

Start with creating [features](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html):

```
 for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
     features[i] = new ol.Feature({
     population: 4000,
     name : points[i].name,
     geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
     ol.proj.transform([
     points[i].long,
     points[i].lat],
     'EPSG:4326', oProjection))
     });
 }
```

I then populate the clusters with a vector with features:

```
var vSource = new ol.source.Vector({ features: features});

var vFeatures = vSource.getFeatures();

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
                   distance: 20,
                   source: vSource});
```

I then style the clusters with some icons

```
var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: clusterSource,
          style : new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                src: 'image/image.png'})),
          text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: '18px Helvetica, Arial Bold, sans-serif',
                text: size.toString(),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#fff'
                })
})
 map.add(clusters)
```

I later have an onclick method that should get the "name" from the Feature, but the only thing it can print out is the geometry, it is like the name on the object disapears from Clusters. For example, doing a `clusterSource.getFeatures()` returns an empty vector, `[]`.

```
function addOverlays(points){
    for(var i = 0; i<points.length;i++){
        var element = document.getElementById(points[i].id);
        var popup = new ol.Overlay({
            element: element,
            positioning: 'bottom-center',
            stopEvent: false
        });
        map.addOverlay(popup);
        // display popup on click
    }

    // display popup on click
    map.on('click', function(evt) {
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
            function(feature, layer) {
                console.log("feature on click: ",feature);
                return feature;
            });
        if (feature) {
            var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
            var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
            popup.setPosition(coord);
            console.log(feature.get('name'));
            $(element).popover({
                'placement': 'bottom',
                'html': true,
                'content': feature.get('name') //THIS IS THE TROUBLE
            });
            $(element).popover('show');
        } else {
            $(element).popover('destroy');
        }
    });
}
```

The addOverlay method cannot get the name of the feature, it returns "undefined" which is very strange. Help? Any help please? It is like the features stop existing when added in the cluster.

Answer (score 9):

So with clustering, OL3 creates a new feature that wraps all the clustered features underneath it.  If you look at a clustered feature you see this under the values attribute:

```
values_: Object
  features: Array[19]
  geometry: ol.geom.Point
```

This is why `getFeatures()` does not work, when working with cluster features, they only have these two values when they are created.

```
function isCluster(feature) {
  if (!feature || !feature.get('features')) { 
        return false; 
  }
  return feature.get('features').length > 1;
}

map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, 
                  function(feature) { return feature; });
  if (isCluster(feature)) {
    // is a cluster, so loop through all the underlying features
    var features = feature.get('features');
    for(var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
      // here you'll have access to your normal attributes:
      console.log(features[i].get('name'));
    }
  } else {
    // not a cluster
    console.log(feature.get('name'));
  }
});
```

Comment: a very good solution, still I'm having some issues with it with non-cluster singular features, but will get there eventually.

Comment: @radhoo I know this is old but I stumbled on the same problem and I solved it by replacing `feature.get('name')` with `feature.get('features').get('name')` in  else. hope it helps

Comment: Tim's code is already corrected to support both singular features as well as clusters. Your comment is correct and in line with the code posted.

Comment: When we loop through forEachFeatureAtPixel in singleclick event, we are supposed to get the particular feature that we clicked on. but when clustering is active, we have a feature that has features array like this.. var features = feature.get('features'); here features is an array of original feature. in this case how i am gonna find out which one  is the exact feature i have clicked?

Answer (score 3):

I cant add comments yet (not enough reputation), but I want to add my solution on which e.g. Popups will be shown on clustered and unclustered features . Like the example of @Timh.

But when it comes to a lower zoom level and the clustering is "dissolved" the popup will just show `undefined` when you click the feature which was (and technially still is) in a cluster.

So, you can do the same with

```
if (typeof feature.get('features') === 'undefined') {
  // feature.get('whatever');
} else {
  var cfeatures = feature.get('features');
  for(var i = 0; i < cfeatures.length; i++) {
    //like in  the example of timh
  }
}
```

and getting e.g Popups from clustered, unclustered and from features which are not clustered (in a visual way) at the moment.

**Edit**: [Example with Popups](http://www.kreidefossilien.de/webgis/dokumentation/beispiele/show-popups-on-clustered-features)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to your layers and their source, my mistake is that i should set:

```
layer.getSource().getSource().getFeatures()
```

instead of:

```
layer.getSource().getFeatures()
```

Answer (score -1):

I cannot comment since I don't have the rep but this is a comment to Timh's solution which is good but has a flaw  (which is why radhoo has problems with single features as described in his comment).

The "isCluster" function should not check if there are one or more features since it's still a cluster even if it only contains one feature

```
function isCluster(feature) {
  return !feature || !feature.get('features');
}
```

So it's better to handle all clusters in the same way and optionally handle feature objects separately.